# Check how iOS application was installed

Tags: ios

I was wondering if there is a way to check how an application was installed to device in any of the following ways.

- Installed via iTunes by way of their PC/Mac.
- Installed directly from appStore.
- Installed via Xcode.
- Installed via MDM (Mobile device management).
- Installed from an adhoc profile.
- Installed via the B2B store.

I would also like to know whether or not it is possible to check if the iPhone is set up for development or not?

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What will you do with this knowledge?  There may be a better way.  Do you want to check for your application or all applications in general?

Comment: The application I am working on will be distributed in a variety of ways and by multiple sub-clients. My client wants direct reporting back from each application as to how it was installed. I am not 100% sure on why they need this information I was just trying to see whether or not it was possible.

Comment: Can you make different builds for different distribution channels?  Then you can just hard code a value.

Comment: Yes and no, For the iTunes build and adhoc build this was my fall back plan. The only problem is the adhoc build can be distributed in lots of ways (iTunes install, MDM etc). Hard coding will be my fall back option. Thanks for your help. Any ideas about checking if a phone is set up for development or not?

Comment: Most of these distribution channels would probably have a unique App ID which could be retrieved using the keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no.  There is no mechanism to do this.  As mentioned in the comments, the only real way would be to assign a version number to each build and append it with say a, b, c...
But again, that's not perfect.

As you said in your comments, this is for a client; however, it might be wise to talk to your client as to why want this data to see if theirs an underlying analytical feature they're interested that might be more easily accessible.

Comment: Thanks, I have been unsuccessful so far finding anything of use outside of hardcoding values. Not including this feature is an option just wanted to explore it more before I gave an answer.